# C# algorithm for figuring out different possible combinations

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, combinations

I have 10 boxes, each box can hold one item from a group/type of items, each 'group' type only fits in one of the 10 box types. The item pool can have n number of items. The groups have completely distinct items. Each item has a price, i want an algorithm that will generate all the different possibilities, so i can figure out different price points vs custom rank/weight assignment to each of the items, based on item attributes.

so a smaller picture of the problem

> BOX A - can have item 1,2,3,4 in it
>
> BOX B - can have item 6,7,8,9,10,11,12
>
> BOX C - can have item 13,15,16,20,21

**More Detail**
The solution would be a set of BOX A, BOX B, AND BOX C, having the greatest rank based on the set of boxes. Each box can only contain ONE of the designated items for that box.
An item is an object, the object has 3 attributes(firmness, elasticity, strength). Each attribute can have 1-100 for a score. The goal is to enter a weight for each attribute, then the logic will run through ALL items and determine the top ranked item combinations based on the weights for each attribute. I have used 3 attributes for each item for ease of explanation, but items can have about 10 different attributes.

The items are stored in a db, they have a column which denotes which box they can go in. All box types are stored in an array, and I can put the items in a generic list. Anyone see a straightforward way to do this.

I have tried doing 10 nested foreach's to see if i could find a simpler way. The nested loops will take MANY hours to run. the nested for each's basically pull all combinations, then calculate a rank for each combination, and store the top 10 ranked combination of items for output

Comment: Generating all the possibilities is almost certainly not the best way to solve your problem. Perhaps you could spend a little more time describing the problem you are trying to solve rather on how you are attempting to solve it? I think you might get more useful answers that way.

Comment: I added a 'more detail' paragraph

Comment: If you need speed, after you get the foreach to work you could convert them to for loops as that may give you a little less overhead and increase in performance.

Comment: Are the algorithms for calculating the weight for each attribute the same?  If the the formula is linear then the solution might be much easier than you realize, such as pulling out items from the DB in a sorted order.

Comment: No, each attribute can have a different weight assigned to it.

Comment: Are you looking for the top ranked items for each box or for all the boxes combined?  Or are you looking at how to populate the boxes from the db?  Could you post a sample of the code, maybe that will make it easier to figure out what you are looking for.

Comment: Why do you need all combinations? From your description, it seems that the best solution is to take the best item for each box. In which case you simply need to compute the value of each item and pick the item of maximum value for each box.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to get the "best" item from each box, as adding the scores of the best item in each group will give the best overall total.  If so, you should be able to do this all in the database with a decent query or in a simple LINQ-to-objects query on the client side if desired.  Since I'm not an SQL person, I'll just go with the client approach.  Using the obvious definition for the Item class:

```
public static double Score<T>(T item, IEnumerable<Weighting<T>> weights)
{
    return weights.Aggregate(0.0, (p, w) => p + w.Apply(item));
}

public static T MaxBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, double> selector)
{
    double curMax = double.MinValue;
    T curItem = default(T);
    foreach (T i in items)
    {
        double curValue = selector(i);
        if (curValue > curMax) 
        {
            curMax = curValue;
            curItem = i;
        }
    }
    return curItem;
}

public class Weighting<T>
{
    public Weighting(double weight, Func<T, double> attributeSelector)
    {
        _weight = weight;
        _attributeSelector = attributeSelector;
    }

    private readonly double _weight;
    private readonly Func<T, double> _attributeSelector;

    public double Apply(T item) { return _weight * _attributeSelector(item); }
}

Weighting<Item>[] weights = {new Weighting<Item>(1, i => i.Elasticity),
                             new Weighting<Item>(2, i => i.Firmness),
                             new Weighting<Item>(.5, i => i.Strength)};

var hsQuery = from i in allItems
              group i by i.Box into boxItems
              select boxItems.MaxBy(bi => Score(bi, weights));
```

I imagine there's a clever way to make the weighted score be a calculated column in an SQL query that you can then `group by box where score = max(score)` and get the result directly from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an [outstanding C# library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx) for permutations and combinatorics.

It provides efficient algorithms for this class of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was what you were looking for, but based on what I can infer from your question, using LINQ will be a lot simpler to code.  Here's my guesstimate of what the answer should be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Box
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Firmness { get; set; }
        public int Elasticity { get; set; }
        public int Strength { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public int FirmnessWt { get; set; }
        public int ElasWt { get; set; }
        public int StrWt { get; set; }

        public int ItemScore
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    (Firmness * FirmnessWt) +
                    (Elasticity * ElasWt) +
                    (Strength * StrWt);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // set the rankings
            int firmnessWt = 20;
            int elasWt = 40;
            int strWt = 80;

            // generate the items
            Item item1 = new Item { Id = 1, Elasticity = 1, Firmness = 4, Strength = 2, ElasWt=elasWt, FirmnessWt=firmnessWt, StrWt=strWt };
            Item item2 = new Item { Id = 2, Elasticity = 2, Firmness = 3, Strength = 4, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item3 = new Item { Id = 3, Elasticity = 3, Firmness = 2, Strength = 1, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item4 = new Item { Id = 4, Elasticity = 4, Firmness = 1, Strength = 3, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };

            Item item6 = new Item { Id = 6, Elasticity = 1, Firmness = 5, Strength = 2, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item7 = new Item { Id = 7, Elasticity = 1, Firmness = 4, Strength = 4, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item8 = new Item { Id = 8, Elasticity = 1, Firmness = 3, Strength = 1, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item9 = new Item { Id = 9, Elasticity = 2, Firmness = 2, Strength = 3, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item10 = new Item { Id = 10, Elasticity = 2, Firmness = 3, Strength = 2, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item11 = new Item { Id = 11, Elasticity = 2, Firmness = 2, Strength = 4, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item12 = new Item { Id = 12, Elasticity = 3, Firmness = 6, Strength = 1, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };

            Item item13 = new Item { Id = 13, Elasticity = 3, Firmness = 5, Strength = 4, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item15 = new Item { Id = 15, Elasticity = 2, Firmness = 4, Strength = 5, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item16 = new Item { Id = 16, Elasticity = 3, Firmness = 2, Strength = 5, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item20 = new Item { Id = 20, Elasticity = 3, Firmness = 1, Strength = 7, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };
            Item item21 = new Item { Id = 21, Elasticity = 3, Firmness = 1, Strength = 4, ElasWt = elasWt, FirmnessWt = firmnessWt, StrWt = strWt };

            // populate the 3 boxes with the generated items
            List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>
            {
                new Box
                {
                    Id = "A",
                    Items = new List<Item> { item1, item2, item3, item4 }
                },
                new Box
                {
                    Id="B",
                    Items = new List<Item> { item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12 }
                },
                new Box
                {
                    Id="C",
                    Items = new List<Item> { item13, item15, item16, item20, item21 }
                }
            };

            // calculate top candidate for firmness
            List<Item> items = boxes.SelectMany(c => c.Items).ToList();

            Item firmnessCandidate = items.OrderByDescending(a => a.Firmness).First();

            // calculate top candidate for elasticity
            Item elasticityCandidate = items.OrderByDescending(b => b.Elasticity).First();


            // calculate top candidate for strength
            Item strengthCandidate = items.OrderByDescending(c => c.Strength).First();

            // calculate top candidate by combined weight
            Item weightCandidate = items.OrderByDescending(w => w.ItemScore).First();

            Console.WriteLine("Firmness - id:" + firmnessCandidate.Id.ToString() + ", score: " + firmnessCandidate.Firmness.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Elasticity - id:" + elasticityCandidate.Id.ToString() + ", score: " + elasticityCandidate.Elasticity.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Strength - id:" + strengthCandidate.Id.ToString() + ", score: " + strengthCandidate.Strength.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Item score - id:" + weightCandidate.Id.ToString() + ", score: " + weightCandidate.ItemScore.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

HTH...

Comment: not sure this does the trick, as the solution should be the 'SET' of boxes, so 1 A, 1 B, 1 C. The weight would be calculated per SET. This is a good solution as it's set based, which is much more desirable than row based

I have modified the description of the problem to be more exact.

Comment: Maybe you can post a sample of your code... it's not very clear what you want based on just the details you provided. Where its very hazy is "top ranked item combinations".  Not sure if you want the highest ranked item by weight, or the box itself, or both... Definitely can do this with O(n), I believe.

Comment: A box can only contain ONE item. so the rank will be the set of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a binary program, where

```
maximize $\sum_i c_i x_i$ (value function)


$x_i \in \{ 0, 1 \} \forall i$ (binary constraint)

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1$ (exactly one item in box a constraint)

$x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{12} = 1$

$x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{16} + x_{20} + x_{21} = 1$

$\sum_i p_i x_i <= P$ (price constraint)
```

(paste the above into a LaTeX evaluator, like math.se, to see the symbols)

This can be optimized using branch-and-bound in far fewer steps than evaluating every combination.