# How do I run a .NET Unit Test repeatedly with a set of parameters cartesianed

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, t4

I have 1 unit test method that needs several parameters.  I would like to run this test once for every possible value of a cartesian with a predefined list for each parameter.  I imagine that parameters could be passes in via the test context, but I do not want to connect to an external database.

For example:  If I had 2 parameters with the following possible values, the test would execute 6 times (order doesn't matter). (pseudo-code)

```
p1 = { 1, 5, 10 }
p2 = { "blue", "red" }

test 1: ( 1, "red" )
test 2: ( 5, "red" )
test 3: ( 10, "red" )
test 4: ( 1, "blue" )
test 5: ( 5, "blue" )
test 6: ( 10, "blue" )
```

Note: I'm using the built-in Visual Studio 2010 unit testing, not NUnit or one of the many other unit test frameworks.

## Edit:

I'm storing the possible values as enumerations in the test class, but it is also reasonable to use arrays.  My goal is to automate the link between the source enumerations/arrays and the actual test.  While my sample only has 2 parameters with 6 permutations, the actual set is much larger.  I do not want to skip a scenerio just because I missed something in a manual conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is: You can use "Data-driven tests".  You can store your values in comma-seperated-value files, XML files, or SQL database files.  I've been doing this with VS2k8, so your process with VS2k10 may be a little bit different.

First, create a file with your test data.  If you create a CSV file, it might look like

> param1, param2
>   1, blue
>   1, red
>   5, blue
>   5, red
>   10, red
>   10, blue

Go to "Test View", select the test you want to use the data with.  In properties, click the ellipsis dots next to "Data Connection String".  Specify your file.

Now, in your unit test code, you will specify the data from your file as
`testContext.DataRow("param1")` and `testContext.DataRow("param2")`.

When you run the test, you will get a test result for each data row the test runs with.  How convenient!

**Update** If you want to automatically use Cartesian products of parameters that are kept as enumerations, you might want to use nested for loops like

> dim testResults as dictionary(of triplet,string)
>     for each x as foo in fooCollection
>      for each y as bar in barCollection
>      for each z as foobar in foobarCollection
>   Try
>   ' test code
>   testResults.add(new triplet(x,y,z),"PASS")
>   catch ex as exception
>   testResults.add(new triplet(x,y,z),"ERROR: " + ex.toString())
>   End try

Comment: Using a data driven test makes sense.  But is there any way to automate the cartesian?  I do not want to manually maintain the data file.  I'll edit the question to elaborate.

Comment: The T4 toolbox can generate code, text, etc. from existing code including enumerations.  I'll use its sample of generating SQL from enumerations as a starting point to generate the CSV from.  http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

you can do that with a tool like Gallio in .net

```
[Test]
[Row(0, 0)]
[Row(1, 1)]
public void Lower_bounds(int x, int expectedResult)
{
   int result = Fibonacci.Calculate(x);
   Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Tip 1 : You could extend this further by learning about the [Factory] attribute in Gallio.
Tip 2 : Pair-wise helps you to generate combination

Thank you Jeroen for Editing the code and for the support

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. I took the liberty to edit your answer by using this little `indent code by 4 spaces` trick. Now the source code is a bit more readable. BTW: Galileo is a nice idea, so I upvoted your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

For this type of testing, definitely consider [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) over rolling your own.

However, why not create an outer test which [generates all the combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695179/c-algorithm-for-figuring-out-different-possible-combinations) from your sets at runtime and calls the test method once for each combination?

Answer (score 0):

As @hemp mentioned, you can use an outer test that generates all the permutations of your enums.  The class at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx looks pretty interesting.

However, is testing all possible combinations just a sanity check?  To me it's a code smell, and I would look for edge cases instead of bogging down test run time with running the permutations.  Just a thought. :)

Comment: It is basicly a combination of sanity checking and load testing.  It includes the testing of an external interface, and for unforeseen threading interactions of the underlying code (that I don't own and has interesting 'known bugs').  The design isn't easily unit testable, but can be tested as a whole.

Comment: Gotcha, that's an unfortunate situation, but I understand why you'd want to do this now.

Comment: @chilltemp: if threading interactions is one of the things you're trying to test, I highly encourage looking at a tool like [Typemock Racer](http://bit.ly/e70jHx) ([introduction](http://bit.ly/dI8bVX)).

Answer (score 0):

@Rising Star's idea of using a data driven was the best solution.  I used that in conjunction with a T4 script to generate a CSV containing the cartesianed enums.  Here is the script for your reference (uses the [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/)).

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".csv" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#
    List<CodeEnum> enums = GetEnums("TestClass.cs");    
    bool first = true;

    // Header
    foreach(CodeEnum e in enums)
    {
        if(first)
            first = false;
        else
            Write(",");

        Write(e.Name);
    }
    WriteLine("");

    // Data
    WriteData(enums);
#>
<#+
    private void WriteData(List<CodeEnum> enums)
    {
        WriteData(enums, new string[enums.Count], 0);
    }

    private void WriteData(List<CodeEnum> enums, string[] values, int level)
    {   
        foreach (CodeElement element in enums[level].Children)
        {
            values[level] = element.Name;

            if(level + 1 < enums.Count)
            {
                WriteData(enums, values, level + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLine(string.Join(",", values));
            }
        }
    }

    private List<CodeEnum> GetEnums(string enumFile)
    {
        ProjectItem projectItem = TransformationContext.FindProjectItem(enumFile);
        FileCodeModel codeModel = projectItem.FileCodeModel;
        return FindEnums(codeModel.CodeElements);
    }

    private List<CodeEnum> FindEnums(CodeElements elements)
    {
        List<CodeEnum> enums = new List<CodeEnum>();

        FindEnums(elements, enums);

        return enums.Count == 0
            ? null
            : enums;
    }

    private void FindEnums(CodeElements elements, List<CodeEnum> enums)
    {
        foreach (CodeElement element in elements)
        {
            if (element is CodeEnum)
                enums.Add((CodeEnum)element);

            FindEnums(element.Children, enums);
        }
    }
#>
```